saving ML models with pickle to be deployed using Flask
I trained some ensemble Ml to predict, I needed to save with pickle so as to be able to deploy using Flask. To save with pickle I have tried several methods and read several articles but could not get a clue, when trying to use Linear Regression in flask I got error the LR is not defined.
please how do I save the entire Ensemble models with pickle command. And the write path to deploy in Flask to be able to make predictions.
Thank you for your help

Hi @KehindeOlatunji, welcome to the site. It is difficult to identify the problem if we cannot look at the code to reproduce the error; please, consider adding the code to your question.

There’s not enough information here for us to help you. What machine learning library/framework are you using? And why are you using pickle? You should use a library-specific serialization format (tensorflow is SavedModel, PyTorch is .pt and MAR, scikit learn is .joblib) and then cache it in your server, or use an object storage (S3, GCS) to read the saved model weights when you want to make a prediction.
